# Property 'myArray' not found on object of type 'MyVC *' Swift to Obj-C passing array Error

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is my Swift File

```
@objcMembers class MyVC: NSObject {
    
    var myArray = [String]()
    
...
```

This is my ServiceControlVC.m Objective-C File

```
...
        MyVC *vc = [MyVC alloc];
        
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray new];
        items = weakSelf.myModel.myModelArray;

        vc.myArray = items; // xxx this is the error point my compiler get crazy
...
```

I am getting this error:
Property 'myArray' not found on object of type 'MyVC *'

Other properties seems okay, there is something missing point about object type or pointer for this arrray( my guess )

What should I do get rid of this compile error ? Can you tell me why this casting problems happens and how I define my
MyVC swift file property :

`var myArray = [String]()` is a bad approach for this case ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class needs to be a `NSObject` subclass and you could either:

- use `[String]` type, but recognize that it is only exposing it as a `NSArray <NSString *> *` type to Objective-C and is employing copy semantics; or
- alternatively, make your array a `NSMutableArray` type, not a Swift `Array` (but lose the great [generic](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) behavior of the Swift [`Array`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) type).

---

Consider this type defined in Swift:

```
@objcMembers class Foo: NSObject {
    var strings: [String] = []
    var alternateStrings: NSMutableArray = []
}
```

And then consider this Objective-C behavior:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

NSMutableArray <NSString *> *items = [NSMutableArray new];
[items addObject:@"foo"];

foo.strings = items;
foo.alternateStrings = items;

[items addObject:@"bar"];

NSLog(@"myArray: %@", foo.strings);                // ["foo"]
NSLog(@"anotherArray: %@", foo.alternateStrings);  // ["foo", "bar"]
```

It comes down to the question of whether you really want to expose the array as mutable (probably not), or whether you are OK with the copy semantics that Swift `[String]` (aka `Array<String>`) exposes to Objective-C. (Frankly, even if the array is internally mutable, we often prefer to use copy semantics, anyway, to avoid unintended sharing and the problems that introduces.)

---

Regarding your compiler error about your property not being found, perhaps the issue is that when you change the Swift code, we need to compile before the `{Module}-Swift.h` header file will be regenerated.

Comment: according to your comment : NSMutableArray <NSString *> *myModelArray seems like solved the issue..

Answer (score 1):

Make it sub of `: NSObject`

```
@objcMembers class MyVC : NSObject {
   var myArray = [String]()
}
```

Comment: it is already NSObject nothing changed. I think it is about object type but can't find solution